# How to recover the apps of my iPhone after a new setup of itunes

Tags: itunes, iphone

I recently had to restore my computer. Before that, I saved the files "Apple Computer" supposed to contain all my data got on iTunes.

So after a new setup of iTunes, I erased the new "Apple Computer" files with the one I saved in order to recover all my data (apps, music, pictures,...).
But it did not happen.

My iPhone was well recognized by iTunes (I did not have to authorize once more my computer) but all my apps, music and pictures had disappeared.

I know I have to transfer the items from my iPhone to iTunes to get them back on iTunes, but I had items saved on iTunes and not present on my iPhone.

So how can I recover these item I only had on iTunes ?

Thanks for your answers !

Answer (score 1):

Apple's new iTunes in the Cloud service should show you re-download purchased items.

I believe the folder you actually want to copy to preserve your data is `Music\iTunes\*` in your home directory.

If you had items that you did not purchase through Apple, and were not synchronized to your iPhone, then they are likely gone short of using data recovery software on your harddrive.

Answer (score 0):

Transfer purchases directly. This process may be changing due to the cloud service. [This is the apple kb article on it](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1848)

Comment: I've already done this transfer the last time I restore my computer but I only got all the apps present on my iPhone and I've lost all the ones only saved on iTunes and no more present on my iPhone.

To be more clear, I bought apps that were free for a short time (found on iPhon.fr). But I did not have enough place on my iPhone to  get them on my iPhone and I decided to save them only on iTunes. So now they are not present on my iPhone.

Therefore, my problem is how can I get back these items.